# SQL Linked Server to Access Database, Connecting through Classic ASP. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, linked-server

I have a linked server set up on server1 to an access database (DATABASE1).
Provider Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine OLE DB provider.
Local login (me) set up as impersonate
For a login not listed, connections will be made using security context
remote login: me
password: blank

From server1 sql Server instance I can access the linked server and query the tables. 
I have an instance of SQL management express on server2 but when I try and access the linked server from server2 I get the error message.

> "Failed to retrieve data for this request. Cannot initialize the data
>   source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for linked
>   server "DATABASE1" (Microsoft SQL Error 7303)

I am also trying to connect to the linked server in my classic asp web application.

```
adoConlinked.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=anotherdatabasenotlinked;Data Source=IPaddress; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=me;Password"%>

Set adoConlinked = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")%>
 <!--#include file="includes/adoConlinked.inc"-->


 SQLXREF = "SELECT * FROM [DATABASE1]...[Product] where PartNumber = '"
 & request.form("part") &"'and XREF = 'SOMETHING'"


Set SQLXREF2 = adoConlinked.Execute(SQLXREF)
```

But retrieve the following error

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server
>   "DATABASE1" returned message "Cannot start your application. The
>   workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another
>   user."

Answer (score 1):

Solution - On Server1 gave everyone full permission on
 C:\Users[SQL Service account name]\AppData\Local\Temp

Moved the Access file to Server1 and re-linked the server

Answer (score -1):

If the access file is open, it cannot be reopened by another application.

Make sure that your Access file is not open.

Comment: Yes, it isn't open

Comment: If I run a query, even with (nolock) in SQL against the database on server1, I get a result but I also get an .ldb file in the folder where the database is. I can delete the ldb file.